# Phrase for poetically skipping a word because it's been previously said

Tags: phrase-requests

A professor of mine once used a phrase or term for skipping a word of a poetic statement that has already been said. His example was that "a stitch in time saves nine" should really be "a stitch in time saves nine *stitches*", but since you already know the subject of the sentence, it can just be skipped over.

Does anyone know a phrase to describe that?

Comment: It's not paricularly "poetic". It's just the standard "deletion" of predictably repeated elements, which routinely happens in all contexts (but is *slightly less common* in extremely formal contexts, such as legal documents).

Comment: The less common more drastic deletion to 'A stitch in time' etc was common among some pupils at the school I was at (_as_ a pupil).

Comment: @FumbleFingers My professor used it in a poetic context (he was going over why some poetry in ancient languages can be difficult to decipher because the rules for deletion (thanks for the phrase) aren't always known, so interpretation is needed for which subject is the right one. It makes sense that it could be used outside of poetry, though!

Comment: It applies to all sorts of contexts and constructions, but it's very much rule-governed. You can't delete just anything; *_This is a very long book and that is an extremely short_ doesn't work. You have to have something after _short_, like _one_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the technical term is ***ellipsis***.

You can check the definition [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ellipsis). [Here](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/ellipsis.html) you can find plenty of synonyms so you can have your pick.

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have thought that the word for "..." could be used in that way, but it makes perfect sense. Does the sentence, "'A stitch in time saves nine' contains an ellipsis." make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. You could also say _Ellipsis is used in the sentence 'A stitch in time saves nine.'_